# Windows Firewall with Advanced Security - DHCP leakage?

Tags: windows-7, firewall, dhcp

When I start the program ["dhcptest.exe"](https://github.com/CyberShadow/dhcptest) (on Win7), I get a firewall warning. Blocking creates two new Inbound Rules, blocking TCP and UDP. (no outbound rules). When I run the test, it sends a DHCP request (no surprise), and gets a DHCP response (WTF?). The DHCP response clearly comes through to the executable, which reports it.

There is of course a DHCP inbound rule which permits the DHCP client to receive DHCP replies, but the client is not accepting the new DHCP offers -- and it doesn't matter anyway, when I disable that rule the dhcptest.exe program is still reporting the DHCP offer.

How, why? DHCP offers are a connectionless broadcast protocol, so it's not like it should be coming in on a connection created by the outgoing request.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program first starts listening on port 68. This triggers the firewall message. The messages Windows shows are only about “servers”. Outgoing connections are not affected.

Then, when you select to send a DHCP request, an association is created. This association allows responses to reach the program.

Windows notices the program is sending to the broadcast address and as such allows replies to arrive. Otherwise, a program could never perform discovery of services on the local network.

UDP is indeed connectionless. However, “connection” tracking is still required in many cases, like stateful firewalls or NAT. When a packet is sent, a temporary association is created. It expires after some time without traffic.

From the [“How Windows Firewall Works” article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755604(v=ws.10).aspx) (emphasis mine):

> **Because UDP is a connectionless protocol and has no sequence numbers or flags, it has no mechanism for terminating and closing a connection.** Therefore, the timeout for UDP connections is much shorter than that for TCP connections. **The timeout for established but inactive UDP connections is 60 seconds.** In other words, if an established UDP connection is inactive for 60 seconds, the state table entry for that connection is removed from the NAT Mapping Table. This behavior applies to UDP connections on all ports.
>
> There are some exceptions to the 60-second timeout for UDP connections. **When a computer sends a multicast or broadcast message, Windows Firewall waits for up to 3 seconds for a unicast response.** In essence, the state table entry for multicast or broadcast connections is maintained for up to 3 seconds; if the multicast or broadcast connection is inactive for 3 seconds (that is, there is no response), then the state table entry is deleted from the NAT Mapping Table. **Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) multicast messages are a special case and are exempt from the 3-second timeout.**